# Bing Ads api - invalid credentials error

Tags: php, bing-api

So, our BingAds reporting program, which has been running for many months, is suddenly plagued with 105 (InvalidCredentials) errors. The access token had expired, so I requested a new one, which succeeds, giving me a new access token that expires in the future.

```
    $accessTokenExchangeUrl = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf";

    $accessTokenExchangeParams = array();
    $accessTokenExchangeParams['client_id']     = $this->client_id();
    $accessTokenExchangeParams['client_secret'] = $this->client_secret();
    $accessTokenExchangeParams['grant_type']    = 'refresh_token';
    $accessTokenExchangeParams['refresh_token'] = $code;

    // Create an HTTP client and execute an HTTP POST request to
    // exchange the authorization token for an access token and
    // refresh token.
    $httpClient = new HttpClient();
    $responseJson = $httpClient->postData( $accessTokenExchangeUrl, $accessTokenExchangeParams);

    // The response formatted in json
    $responseArray = json_decode($responseJson, TRUE);

    // If the response contains an access_token element, it was successful.
    // If not, an error occurred - throw an exception
    if (isset($responseArray['access_token']))
    {
        return $responseArray;

    }
```

But then using that new token results in a 105 error:

```
$proxy = \BingAds\Proxy\ClientProxy::ConstructWithCredentials($wsdl, $bingUserName, 
                                                                     $bingPasswd, 
                                                                     $developer_token, 
                                                                     $access_token);

$report = new KeywordPerformanceReportRequest();
$report->Format = ReportFormat::Tsv;
$report->ReportName = 'Keyword Performance Report';
$report->ReturnOnlyCompleteData = false;

    <report definition>

$encodedReport = new SoapVar($report, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'KeywordPerformanceReportRequest', $proxy->GetNamespace());

$this->bingReportRequestID = $this->_BingSubmitGenerateReport( $proxy, $encodedReport );
$request = new SubmitGenerateReportRequest();
$request->ReportRequest = $report;

$retval = $proxy->GetService()->SubmitGenerateReport($request)->ReportRequestId;
     ::> throws a SoapFault
```

Any ideas? Like I said, it was working fine for months, now suddenly, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using a refresh_token to authenticate. With the new token you got, you need to generate you new refresh_token and use that one instead.